# Handle checkboxes in Input::all() in Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I want to update my model with following code:

```
$feature = Feature::find($id)->update(Input::all());
```

This works for all fields except the "done"-field which is a boolean in the table and represented by checkbox in the edit form.

```
{{ Form::label('done', 'Done?')}}
{{ Form::checkbox('done',1)}}
```

How can i handle checkboxes with update and Input:all() ?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you avoid using `Input::all()`. That way, you are allowing anyone with minimal HTML knowledge to update fields that shouldn't be editable on your model. Even if you define `$accessible` on your model, it's too risky.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I'm going to use `Input:all()` only for those models, which the user can edit anyway. Attributes that shouldn't be edited by the user therefore will be guarded.

Comment: Using the $fillable array in the model is a good idea when using Input::all(). From the docs: "The fillable property specifies which attributes should be mass-assignable. This can be set at the class or instance level. The inverse of fillable is guarded, and serves as a "black-list" instead of a white-list."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a workaround for this

```
{{ Form::hidden('done', 0); }}
{{ Form::checkbox('done', 1); }}
```

Comment: This is the way to do!

Comment: If you checked 'done' and validation failed, wouldn't they both be auto-filled with 1? Then the next submit it wouldn't matter if they unchecked it, it would still come across as checked. A work-around would be to manually add the HTML for the hidden input to avoid it being populated after validation.

Comment: Note this will cause a problem (in Laravel 5 at least) if you're using Form::model when editing the record, as the model will automatically change the hidden value to 1 if 'done' was previously set to 1. If you use `<input type="hidden" name="done" value="0">` it avoids any issues with Form::model overriding the value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a quick check before saving.

```
if(!Input::get('someCheckbox')) $feature->someCheckbox = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old one, but i found this way works best when filling form data

```
$myModel->fill(array_merge(['checkBoxName1'=>'0','checkBoxName2'=>'0'], $request->all()));
```

or in case of the OP it would be like this:

```
 $feature = Feature::find($id)->update(array_merge(['checkBoxName1'=>'0','checkBoxName2'=>'0'],Input::all()));
```

I just like it way more than adding a hidden field.